# I am trying to create a table in teradata and it doesn't work

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I am trying to create a table in teradata with sql, but I keep getting the following error:

CREATE TABLE FAILED. [3707] Syntax error, expected something like a name or a Unicode delimited identifier or an 'UDFCALLNAME' keyword or a 'SELECT' keyword or '(' between '(' and the 'WITH' keyword

My goal is to create a table that takes the maximum data, named "verwerkingdatum" in my code for every "contract_nr". Without the create table statement it worked just fine. Now I'm trying to create a table out of this. But I get the error above.

Here is my code:

```
    create table mi_temp.beslagrek_saldo as
    (SEL * FROM( WITH x AS
    (
    SELECT  geld_contract_event_id, contract_nr, contract_soort_code,
    contract_hergebruik_volgnr,
    verwerking_datum,
    event_dat,
    valuta_code,
    saldo_na_muteren_orig,
    saldo_na_muteren_eur,
    saldo_na_muteren_dc_ind,
    valuta_datum,
    geld_transactie_soort_code,
    tegenrekening_nr,
    tegenrekening_naam,
    boek_datum,
    storno_ind,
    mutatie_bedrag_orig,
    mutatie_bedrag_eur,
    mutatie_bedrag_dc_ind,
    soort_overboeking,
    tegenrekening_nr_num,
    automaat_transactie_type,
    automaat_id,
    automaat_datum,
    automaat_tijd,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY contract_nr ORDER BY         
    verwerking_datum DESC) AS RowNum
    FROM    MI_VM_Ldm.vgeld_contract_event
    WHERE verwerking_datum >= 1181201 AND verwerking_datum <= 1181231
    )
    SELECT geld_contract_event_id, contract_nr, contract_soort_code,
    contract_hergebruik_volgnr,
    verwerking_datum,
    event_dat,
    valuta_code,
    saldo_na_muteren_orig,
    saldo_na_muteren_eur,
    saldo_na_muteren_dc_ind,
    valuta_datum,
    geld_transactie_soort_code,
    tegenrekening_nr,
    tegenrekening_naam,
    boek_datum,
    storno_ind,
    mutatie_bedrag_orig,
    mutatie_bedrag_eur,
    mutatie_bedrag_dc_ind,
    soort_overboeking,
    tegenrekening_nr_num,
    automaat_transactie_type,
    automaat_id,
    automaat_datum,
    automaat_tijd
    FROM X
    WHERE RowNum = 1))
```

Comment: (SEL * FROM(  .... pretty sure thats the error

Comment: I changed it to (SELECT * FROM(... but still getting the same error

Comment: I not know terradata but maybe you could rewrite the SQL without using a CTE before it works with CREATE TABLE statement

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Subquery?  select * from (<cte part here>) a where a.rownum = 1

Comment: I don't think you can combine a create table as select and a CTE, at least not in Teradata.  Create your table separately,and  then load it selecting from your CTE.  However, I don't understand what you are trying to do that requires a CTE.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your post correctly, are you are trying to is filter your select so that your rownum = 1. You can just use qualify to accomplish that.

```
    create table foo as (
    SELECT geld_contract_event_id, contract_nr, contract_soort_code,
        contract_hergebruik_volgnr,
        verwerking_datum,
        event_dat,
        valuta_code,
        saldo_na_muteren_orig,
        saldo_na_muteren_eur,
        saldo_na_muteren_dc_ind,
        valuta_datum,
        geld_transactie_soort_code,
        tegenrekening_nr,
        tegenrekening_naam,
        boek_datum,
        storno_ind,
        mutatie_bedrag_orig,
        mutatie_bedrag_eur,
        mutatie_bedrag_dc_ind,
        soort_overboeking,
        tegenrekening_nr_num,
        automaat_transactie_type,
        automaat_id,
        automaat_datum,
        automaat_tijd
    from
    MI_VM_Ldm.vgeld_contract_event
        WHERE verwerking_datum >= 1181201 AND verwerking_datum <= 1181231
    qualify ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY contract_nr ORDER BY  verwerking_datum DESC) =1
) with data;
```

Comment: Another problem is the missing final `) with data` :-)

Comment: Another cut and paste fail!